# Adding a  'Like' button to my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have always had a Like button on my website, absolutesofwater.co.uk.  However it has stopped working.  When I tried to get the code again, the developer site says I need to be registered as a developer.  Does anyone know if I can get the code somewhere else - directly from my FB page maybe?

Many thanks

Comment: JO, please do not type messages in all capitals.  I've edited your post to make it less harmful on the corneas :)

Comment: Quoting the facebook-like tag info, "To debug problems with the 'Like' button, always use the Facebook lint tool: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/"

Answer (score 1):

Use their debugger

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

it will give you your code

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fabsolutesofwater.co.uk%2F" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="height: 62px; width: 100%" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

however,

```
Exception   The page at http://absolutesofwater.co.uk/ could not be reached.
```

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=absolutesofwater.co.uk